# I can't return the value of a POST API in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to automatize some API tests, I am using robotframework. I am trying to get the response of a post API using ExtendedRequestsLibrary. I am getting an 500 Code as a response, rather than 200. I am getting 200, when I send this using postman. Probably, there is something wrong about my Body parameter parsing. Can someone help?

Here's my code:

```
2.3. ResourceInventoryManagement
    AuthorizationTokenGenerator
    ExtendedRequestsLibrary.Create Session    TestName    ${ResourceInventoryManagementURL}
    &{headers2}=    Create Dictionary    Authorization=Bearer ${AuthToken}    Body={"provideAlternative": true}    Content-Type=application/json    transactionId=5
    ${result}=    ExtendedRequestsLibrary.Post Request    TestName    ${ResourceInventoryManagementSubURL}    headers=${headers2}
    Set Global Variable    ${result}
    Log    ${result}
    Log    ${result.json()}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this `Body={"provideAlternative": true}` key:value pair in the `${headers2}` dictionary?
The library will not complain and send it in the request's headers (with the `{}` chars encoded) - but that does look like a payload. A payload you currently are not sending, which is a bit unorthodox for post requests in rest APIs.

If that data is in fact the payload, pass it as the value of the `data` argument of the keyword:

```
&{headers2}=    Create Dictionary    Authorization=Bearer 
${AuthToken}    Content-Type=application/json    transactionId=5
${body}=      Create Dictionary    provideAlternative    ${True}
${result}=    ExtendedRequestsLibrary.Post Request    TestName    ${ResourceInventoryManagementSubURL}    headers=${headers2}    data=${body}
```